# SQL Event Store - One Stream Per Aggregate

Tags: database-design, event-sourcing

I want to know how to design a SQL database as an event store when **each aggregate gets its own stream** of events:

*every `X` represents an event*

```
stream-user-1234: X | X | X | X | X | X
stream-user-7566: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
stream-user-9874: X | X | X
```

---

Would I create a separate table for every user stream?

Or do I somehow manage all users in one table?

---

Requirements:

- Append events
- Keep the events in chronological order
- Read all events of a user
- Read all events of a user after event with a certain number
- Delete events (rarely)

P.S. Would be great if someone provides some example queries for my requirements

Comment: Look at SqlStreamStore

Answer (score 4):

Most examples of SQL backed event stores that I am aware of use a single event table for all aggregates stored in the database.  The basic shape being a BLOB column to hold the event, and then additional columns for useful meta data.

A good reference would be the eventide-project, which has an open source module for building a message store on top of postgresql: [message-store-postgres-database](https://github.com/eventide-project/message-store-postgres-database/tree/master/scripts).  The [messages table](https://github.com/eventide-project/message-store-postgres-database/blob/master/database/table/messages.sql) is pretty straight forward - separate jsonb columns for data and metadata, then additional columns to support efficient query for common use cases.

Gabriel Schenker wrote a series at Los Techies: [How We Got Rid of the Database](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2012/06/12/how-we-got-rid-of-the-database/).

Konrad Garus wrote: [Achieving Consistency in CQRS with a Linear Event Store](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/09/14/achieving-consistency-in-cqrs-with-linear-event-store/).

> Keep the events in chronological order

For a single stream, order is usually maintained by writing out a local sequence number for each event in the stream.  You need to do a little bit of work to ensure that first-writer-wins when performing concurrent writes to the same stream.  Each event in the stream has a `happens-after` relationship with all events that have a lower local sequence number.

Across multiple streams, "order" is not necessarily strictly defined.  There's no guarantee that messages sent across an unreliable network will arrive in the order in which they are sent.  Eventide uses a `global_position` column to track the order that things are written to the database.

Putting timestamps on the events gives you some measure of chronology, but of course if the times are measured using different clocks then you aren't guaranteed a useful ordering.

> Delete events (rarely)

Removing rows from your event table is likely to make you unhappy.  Consider marking rows deleted, or overwriting the event data, rather than introducing gaps in the record.

The usual discipline in event sourcing is to repair business errors by adding the appropriate compensating event, rather than trying to change history.

> you're required to delete data by law (GDPR)

There's been a lot of discussion of that in the community.  The real answer is that you need to make data privacy a first class concern in your design.  Replacing the event with a copy that does not include the sensitive information is one possible approach, storing the sensitive information outside of the event history (in a dedicated secrets manager) is another possibility.

NOTE: the above should not be considered legal advice applicable to any jurisdiction.

Comment: What is the consensus on how a reader should poll the Events table? If we read, we may have gaps in our database ID sequence for uncommitted records. We might also have gaps for records that were not successfully inserted. If the reader naively uses last sequence id as the measure for identifying new records, we may miss events in processing.

Comment: Great, that helped. But I am a bit concerned about putting a big number of events in one table!?

Comment: Also about deleting events: Suppose you're required to delete data by law (GDPR).